# Cassandra Astyanax Composite Column

Tags: cassandra, composite-key, astyanax

I'm currently trying to figure out whether I can access composite columns in Cassandra without using the AnnotatedCompositeSerializer. I'm looking for a method similar to what Hector does, using the Composite class and adding components.

I have search in Google but wasn't able to find any hints except for the AnnotatedCompositeSerializer. I want to use the composite key as a row key by the way.

Any hints on where to look next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [PrefixedSerializer](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Composite-columns#how-to-use-the-prefixedserializer-but-you-really-should-use-composite-columns) from the wiki page.